# Read file structure with client-JS when the client is the server?

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

In google chrome and many other browsers, you can pull up website files locally (in chrome you do this with the `file://` url prefix).

Is it possible to read the local file system with client-side JS if the website was loaded from the local file system? or is this not possible period?

Comment: You want to read the files on the server? Or you trying to write code that accesses the file system?

Comment: Second part. Access file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to read the local file system with client-side JS if
>   the website was loaded from the local file system?

You can use `filesystem:` URL scheme.

See [Debugging the Filesystem API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Debugging-the-Filesystem-API)

> `filesystem:` URL FTW. It’s handy to open the `filesystem:` URL for
>   the root `DirectoryEntry` of your app’s origin. What does that mean?
>   For example, if your app lives on `www.example.com`, open
>   filesystem:http://www.example.com/temporary/ in a new tab. Chrome will
>   show a read-only list of the files/folders stored your app origin. For
>   more info on `filesystem:` URLs, see
>   http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-filesystemurls.

You can also enable `Filesystem inspection` at `DevTools` to view folders and files at `Resources` -> `FileSystem`